# How to deal with survival analysis when censoring time depends on a covariate

Tags: survival, censoring, stratification

I'm performing survival analysis on time to drop out of a certain program. However, the censoring of each case depends heavily on the length of the program. For example, some programs only last 3 months, while some can last up to 18 months. Programs of length 6, 9, and 12 months account for 80% of the observations. They are censored only if they do not drop out at the end of the program, therefore the time of censoring depends greatly on program length

I would like to ask for best practices on creating an appropriate estimation when censoring depends on one of the covariates. So far these are the options that I came up with

1. Create one estimator for all observations, but it feels odd when a person joining a 3-month program would have a survival function of 18 months
2. Create one estimator for each group of program length, but some groups only have a small number of observations, so I'm not sure if it can produce a good estimator. The large number of estimators can also be a problem
3. Bin the programs by length, then create one estimator for each bin. This seems more sensible but I'm not sure if there's any caveat.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to engage in some exploratory data analysis.
The choice of model will depend on your understanding of the factors that contribute to dropout. If the *rate* of dropout isn't a function of program length *per se* (except that you can't drop out of a program after it's ended), you might be able to put all of the data together in a single model, even though some interpretations might seem odd (precisely *because* you can't drop out of a program after it's ended). That might work well if most dropouts are early in time regardless of program length. An alternative would be to express the time-to-dropout as a fraction of the program length. Including the program length as a covariate would be wise in either case.

This might also be handled with a cure model, where you explicitly model the failure to have an event along with the time-to-event for those who do.